# Do I need blockchain to connect local database's?

Tags: private-blockchain

Hello all and Happy New Year!

My small business and my client use the same vendor application where the vendor application is locally installed at each location. Our client uses barcoding within their business and we use barcoding within our business. But barcoding between each of our databases are not connected (we don't know what their barcode means and vice versa).

I'm thinking..why not connect the two databases through a blockchain db/dapp that will allow just the bare minimum of details so we can know from our clients barcode the client name and maybe a few other details about the item the barcode is attached too.  I don't want to post any private data on a public blockchain from our client. Client name, job title and a number for that item.

Is this an example of where a blockchain dapp would be a good solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blockchain is not a right tool for your job.

You can connect two databases directly and it is orders of magnitude cheaper and efficient to connect them without a blockchain.

Comment: Thank you Mikko for taking the time to answer my question.  I'm not very technical and will need to find who and how databases can be directly connected.  In my search, could you or someone else point me in the right direction on how to connect two databases for barcoding?  

Another idea related to my initial question...What if connecting our two databases through blockchain is a way to begin the process of work in that our client needs to purchase a token to begin the DAPP which would allow the item we receive to be pre-paid.  Just spit-balling here of course.  Like a supply chain solution

Comment: I would say this is a job for any normal software developer. I would contact the company where did you buy this service in the first place.